# Display text when hovering over an icon using React-Icon Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-icons

so I am attempting to display text when you hover over a mouse.
I am using React-Icons library and for styling using Styled-Components

I have 4 icons on my navbar - Home - About - Skills - Work

Each button is its own component in order for the hover to work properly so when i hover over 1 icon it doesnt display the text for all of them

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SkillsButton } from './SkillsBtnElements'

const SkillsBtn = () => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  const onHover = () => {
    setHover(!hover)
  }

  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={onHover} onMouseLeave={onHover} role="button" tabIndex='-3' >
      { hover ? "SKILLS" : <SkillsButton /> }
    </div>
  )
}

export default SkillsBtn;
```

And for styling i have

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { GiGearHammer } from 'react-icons/gi';

export const SkillsButton = styled(GiGearHammer)`
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
  }
  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
`;
```

I do achieve a hover effect, but when I constantly hover the icon the logic seems to get messed up bc then its only the text that appears and when i hover over the text the icon appears...which isn't the desired effect

Example: https://gph.is/g/4ARQoRV

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The abnormal effect is due to the stale closure problem. `{hover ? "SKILLS" : <SkillsButton />}` is being rendered with a stale value of hover.
If you want the text to only appear when the mouse is over the div, try creating two separate functions for onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events. Like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SkillsButton } from './SkillsBtnElements'

const SkillsBtn = () => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  const onHover = () => {
    setHover(true);
  };

  const onLeave = () => {
    setHover(false);
  };
  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={onHover}
      onMouseLeave={onLeave}
      role="button"
      tabIndex="-3"
    >
      {hover ? "SKILLS" : <SkillsButton />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SkillsBtn;
```

Comment: This is progress!! However, would you happen to know why sometimes it gets stuck on the "Text" and doesn't go back to the icon when you're no longer hovering over it?

Ex: https://gph.is/g/EvpYNo5

Comment: It happens because of the stale closure problem. `{hover ? "SKILLS" : <SkillsButton />}` is being rendered with a stale value of hover. You can [read more about stale closures here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat simpler option, use [MUI tooltip component](https://mui.com/components/tooltips/#main-content)

```
<Tooltip title="Delete">
  <IconButton>
    <DeleteIcon />
  </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

   <div
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
    >
      <p>Hover over me</p>
      {isHovered && <p>Show this text on hover</p>}
    </div>
```

when the mouse enters the div element, the isHovered state is set to true, and when it leaves, the state is set to false.

The text inside the conditional rendering ({isHovered &&

Show this text on hover

}) will only be displayed when isHovered is true.